# Re-entering Singapore on a multiple-entry visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, singapore, multiple-entry

I am an Indian citizen on a one-year multiple-entry visitor's visa to Singapore. I am visiting relatives in Singapore. I plan to go to Surabaya for a week and re-enter Singapore for three weeks more with relatives, before returning to India. My air tickets are all confirmed.

How do I get my re-entry visa when I come in from Surabaya?

Comment: Not quite sure what the problem is. Surely if you have a multiple entry visa, you can use that to re-enter?

Comment: Yes you make it sound like you believe you need two visas: your "multi-entry visa" and some "re-entry visa" - what makes you think this might be the case?

Answer (score 4):

A multiple-entry visa is just that, you can enter and exit multiple times, without needing additional re-entry permits.  Singapore does not care where you go between visits.